# Access file/content directly from Alfresco without log in

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

My scenario is this..

I am having a web application which uses the ALFRESCO CMS to display files or images.
What I am doing is I login to alfresco using username and password in a Java servlet and I can able to get a ticket for that login. But I could not able to access the file/image from browser directly with that ticket. When I launch the url (with ticket) from the browser it goes to alfresco login page for credentials.

Do we have any way to login to alfresco programmatically and get the ticket and show the file/content *directly* in browser using that ticket. (Note: I do not want to pass the username and password via GET)

Please help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that following this [Wiki](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/URL_Addressability#Ticket_URL_Argument) page providing the url as a parameter.

So for example it will look like

> /alfresco/download/direct/workspace/SpacesStore/0000-0000-0000-0000/myfile.pdf?ticket=1234567890

Or for short

> /alfresco/d/d/workspace/SpacesStore/0000-0000-0000-0000/myfile.pdf?ticket=1234567890

Comment: Thank you so much for your correction and answer. I can able to get the file from alfresco without logging in using the ticket. But after I access the file using the ticket I can able to access the entire alfresco (If I enter the url). It is internally logs in to alfresco using the ticket. Any solutions not to access the alfresco after accessing using the ticket?

Comment: But if you just want the file....then you could use the new public service of Alfresco. In Alfresco Share 4.2 there is button create public link. This means users can only access that link. If you want the link generated you'll need to do so some extra work

Comment: But, this will make all the contents as public. right?. In token based system after the token expires user cannot access the content again. Making public link will make the link to the content as permanent and also public. right?

Comment: That's true, but you could write a scheduled job which removes public links after a while for example.
Or you make the rest of the system not visible for EVERYONE and set your permissions.