# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 authentication

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, alfresco

When i used following code for display image without authentication then got 401 error..
How to solve this error?

```
<%
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(Constant.USER, Constant.PASSWORD.toCharArray());
    }
});
    String url=request.getAttribute("url").toString();

<img alt="" src="<%=url%>" />
```

I also tried following link but ask me about login credential

http://techtipsjava.blogspot.in/2014/04/securing-restful-apis-with-http-basic.html
http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-to-add-basic-authentication-into-httpurlconnection/140

How can i display image without login credential???
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding 2 tickets won't really help that much. If you have an Alfresco ticket (probably you will with the SSO of Alfresco & Liferay), then you can add the ticket in an url to retrieve the content.

Take a look at the [wiki](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/URL_Addressability#Ticket_URL_Argument) and this StackOverlow Question: [Access file/content directly from Alfresco without log in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22014158/access-file-content-directly-from-alfresco-without-log-in)